# Setting ItemID of a page based on categoryID of articles

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Here is the situation

I am adding some articles within a category that are not linked by a menu item ... when I use JCE to link to these articles from another article, the menu ID of the page displayed is set to the one I am linking from ... This is perfect, the breadcrumbs are working as expected and everything is fine ...

The problem is when I perform a search... when the results return, those linked articles which has no menu item comes back with no itemID

I was wondering if there's a way to modify Joomla Router to set an ItemID for the pages which has no ItemID if they match certain catID ...

I know I will be modifying the core files ... I cannot create hidden menu items because this will disturb the breadcrumbs navigation... The site has huge number of categories so creating menu item for each will be painful!

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly modify the router to look up the catID for a particular article, but it would not accomplish anything unless that category has a corresponding menu item. itemID specifically comes from the itemID so there must be a menu item related to it in order for it to be a valid itemID.

You could modify your search form to pass along the current itemID, but if your search shows up on every page, it would vary depending on where the search was initiated.

If all of your content items can use the same itemID, you might want to simply use an override for your search results and add that particular itemID to all your search results.

I am afraid that there is no simple answer if you do not want to create menu items.

Comment: Unfortunately they are multiple different categories and a single search field ... I have no option but creating links then which is gonna be hard because they are more than 400! Then I'm gonna hide the menus with CSS. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You shouldn't have to hide the menus. Just put all of the menu items in a menu and don't put it in a module position. The links will still work.

Comment: I add them nested from their parent menu item to make sure the breadcrumbs are pointing correctly. and I cannot set the module to hide their level because I need to display some menu items at the same level ... It's complicated :D Thanks for help Brent :) btw what's your company website? Couldn't reach it through your profile

Comment: Wow, that makes it a pain. Company site is bnrbranding.com, should be correct in my profile.